# Is it possible to change the colour of comments in Python Idle?

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, python-idle

I would like to change the default colour of python comments, to something which is visible to me as I am colour blind. Are there any customizable features in Python Idle, or would I have to switch to another platform to be able to change the colour of comments in Python. Thanks.

Comment: As a practical matter, we cannot change the built-in choices.  But users can change each text-on-background combination in a custom configuration, and I expect most will be happier with at least a few changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do

> Options > Configure IDLE > Highlights > Choose Color for:

And select the "Normal Code or Text", and there you'll be able to choose the "Python Comments" option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Options > Configure IDLE > Highlights tab > Choose color for: Python Comments